# MvvmCross WPF Setup - Core could not be found - missing using directive or assembly reference?

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross

Added MvvmCross NuGet package to a new, clean WPF app in Visual Studio 2013, but it cannot build due to the following error on *line 19 of Setup.cs*:

> The type or namespace name 'Core' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried following the instructions in the boilerplate `ToDo-MvvmCross/_Wpf UI.txt` file inserted into the project to no avail.

I'm sure this is a simple fix, but as it might cause others trouble, I'm posting here for help.

Thanks,
jmp

Comment: The `Core` is your core shared project - normally the PCL. Are you referencing it? If you are, have you used a different namespace? (if you have, then no worries - just change the `using` statement to reflect the naming you used)

Comment: Thanks Stuart - we figured it out.  The PCL was referenced, but my default namespace was unexpected by Mvx (I didn't call it "Core".)  Once a colleague of mine realized that Mvx was expecting the App object in the PCL, we fixed up the namespace and all is good.   By the way, thank you for your brilliant framework and stellar support.  We've had great success with MVX so far - looking forward to continuing with it.